# I can't run java program from the CMD my paths may be we

Tags: java

I'm trying to run Welcome.java program from the cmd

```
public class Welcome {  
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
  }
}
```

Before I mention what I have been trying, when I type `where java` into cmd I get two different paths

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
D:\java\jdk\bin\java.exe
```

First I set my current directory to where welcome.java is.

```
C:\Users\user_name\Desktop
```

Then I check if the file exists and it does.

```
dir
```

Then I try to compile the file by typing

```
javac Welcome.java
```

Then I check again to see if welcome.class has been created, I think the issue might be here since I dont see any welcome.class file. I don't know if this is because something is wrong with my paths.

```
dir
```

Then I attempt to run the java interpreter

```
java Welcome
```

After this I don't see any output, it just returns to the next system prompt.

Comment: It should be `javac Welcome.java` and `java Welcome`. What do you see if you run `javac -version` or `java -version`? There isn't much point in showing us that you're executing a `dir` command if you aren't going to show any of the output.

Comment: After I run javac -version I don't see anything I tried both from C and D path's since my jdk is installed in my D drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute these 2 command, you must to configure your system variables.

1. You must to add into your path variable D:\java\jdk\bin or %JAVA_HOME%\bin.
2. You should configure JAVA_HOME creating one new system variable: JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk

To add this variables you can follow this link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0

**You have to restart your PC to load the changes.**

Then, execute:

`javac Welcome.java`

This command should create one Welcome.class in the same directory.
Fianlly, You can execute the command

`java Welcome`

[image]

Comment: *JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk\bin\java.exe* Incorrect. That should be `JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk` But it's not clear what's happening at this point as *no output* should never happen. And the value of `PATH` should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;<what was already there>`

Comment: It is true, I change it. But I should be with the \bin directory no?

Comment: How do I do those 2 things: "You must to add into your path variable D:\java\jdk\bin\java.exe. You should configure JAVA_HOME creating one new system variable: JAVA_HOME=D:\java\jdk\bin"

Comment: I added one link in the post. Check the new JAVA_HOME It is without \bin directory

Comment: You post is still wrong. See my comment

Comment: I think I have the correct JAVA_HOME variable.
variable: ```JAVA_HOME``` value: ```D:\java\jdk```

Comment: Do you check your path variable?

Comment: variable: ```Path``` value: ```C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath``` do I change value to ```D:\java\jdk\bin``` ?

Comment: Yes, You can try it. Remember that you have to restart your PC.

Comment: *do I change value to D:\java\jdk\bin ?*  Well, no! You have to leave what was already there. You can remove anything previous to do with Java, but nothing else

Comment: There was already ``` D:\java\jdk\bin``` addres there when I clicked on edit value. I just bumped it to the top and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check the JAVA_HOME variable and compare to the one specified in your ide.

Change the name of your welcome.java with Welcome.java

Comment: I checked it by running ```echo %JAVA_HOME%``` it outputs this path:
``` D:\java\jdk ```
also changed the name to Welcome.java
for IDE im using Apache Netbeans IDE 17 but I don't know how to check the variable from there I'm currently looking it up

Comment: That *is* correct (assuming those backticks are not involved ;) ) As a temporary test then do `set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"` and then `javac -version` Then you can set that in Env Vars

Answer (score 1):

**You should have the class name and the file name the same (case sensitive)**.

Example:

```
public class FileName{
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
System.out.println("Welcome to Java!"); 
} }
```

Then you should compile it

```
javac FileName.java
```

Check where the environment variables are set to the correct path of the Java platform. You can do this by running these commands:

```
javac -version
```

**"javac -version"** command checks the Java Compiler version (javac)

```
java -version
```

**"java -version"** command checks the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version

Or just type `java` and it should give you a message about how to use the **Java command**.

Comment: The commands ```javac -version``` , ``` java -version``` or ``` java``` does not do anything. No outputs.

Comment: Then the path you specified in the environment variables is wrong. Try giving the path in the System variables section under the path option. If you didn't understand what I was trying to say feel free to ask again.

Comment: Yes apparently my path variable had the wrong value, thank you so much.